# How to limit the results from cloudant search index to say 15 or 20

Tags: node.js, cloudant

I created a search index in Cloudant and trying to access the search index with node. ([Using this tutorial](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#cloudant-search))I get back the response and everything. But I get back around 386 responses.

I read the [Cloudant documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/api?topic=cloudant-search) and found that I can limit the number of results using limit.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
db.search('library', 'books', { q: req },{limit:20}, function(err, result) {
  if (err)
    throw err;

console.log("the  body ", result.length)
  })
```

My search result should be restricted to 20, but I see 386 results

Answer (score 3):

The `q` and the `limit` (and any other parameters you supply to modify the search) should be in the same JS object instead of two separate objects.